# Website grid layout messed up when 3 line title

Tags: css, wordpress, grid-layout

On my website, http://reefbulk.shop/?page_id=1438, you can see 4 articles. They are normally lined up (as on the home page), but for some mysterious reason, they are not on some pages (such as page_id=1438).

I believe I can fix it with CSS, however adding a margin doesn't seem to help.

I hope someone here knows how to fix this infuriating issue. Last time I had it (on my other non-test site), I just made all the images the same dimensions. This has now failed in this new theme I'm using.

Asking the theme maker is no option as they give no support if your membership runs out (which it has).

Answer (score 0):

You could display your articles as grids, using the following CSS on your articles.

```
display: grid;
align-content: space-between;
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to work when I put it in the custom css field. Any tips?